# Berry's curvature and magnetic moment in TMDCs

Tags: transition-metals, berry-phase, 2d-lattice, dichalcogenides, valleytronics

I am studying the transition metal dichalcogenides (TMDCs) and one of the applications that these materials have is their use in [valleytronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleytronics#:%7E:text=Valleytronics%20is%20the%20technology%20of,coined%20in%20analogy%20to%20spintronics.). Valleytronics is related to the magnetic moment, Berry curvature, the spatial inversion symmetries, and the time-reversal symmetry.

According to the time-reversal symmetry, Berry's curvature and magnetic moment are odd functions ($\mathbf{\Omega(-k)}=-\mathbf{\Omega(k)}$ and $\mathbf{m(-k)}=-\mathbf{m(k)}$).
According to the symmetry of spatial inversion, the functions are even ($\mathbf{\Omega(-k)}=\mathbf{\Omega(k)}$ and $\mathbf{m(-k)}=\mathbf{m(k)}$). Therefore, for valleytronics to exist, there does not have to be inversion symmetry, which occurs with a single-layer TMDCs.

- How can I demonstrate that the functions are odd according to the **time reversal symmetry** and even according to the **spatial inversion symmetry**?
- What is the **physical interpretation** of Berry's curvature and Berry's phase?
- H̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶e̶d̶u̶c̶e̶ ̶B̶e̶r̶r̶y̶'̶s̶ ̶e̶q̶u̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶?̶ (Maybe a question for a new thread, since ProfM already answered 2 of the above and I answered the other).

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site, and thank you for asking this question here!!! We hope to see much more of you!! One problem might be that you have 3 questions here, not 1. This might be appropriate as 2 or 3 separate questions.

Comment: I too am trying to master everything Berry in a study of the integer QHE!  Rather than make a poor attempt at explaining what I know, I thought I would point you to a source that I found very useful:  https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/one.pdf.  Section 1.5 is devoted to Berry phase.  Also your mention of transition metal dichalcogenides caught my eye.  30 years ago I was studying charge density waves in them as a graduate student with STM.  My avatar is an STM image of atoms + CDW in 1T-TiSe2.  It is nice to see that they are still systems of scientific interest!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Berry curvature is defined as:

$$
\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k}),
\tag{1}
$$

where $A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})=\langle u_{\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ is the Berry connection, $|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ is a Bloch state, and $\partial_\mu\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial k_\mu}$, and $\mu,\nu=x,y,z$.

**Invesion symmetry.** Under inversion, $\mathbf{k}\to-\mathbf{k}$, so that applying the inversion operation $\mathcal{I}$ on a Bloch state gives $
\mathcal{I}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle=|u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$. If the system is invariant under inversion, then $|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ and $|u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ must be the same state up to a global phase, so that:

$$
\mathcal{I}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle\Longrightarrow |u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle.\tag{2}
$$

For the Berry connection, $\mathcal{I}A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})=A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$. If the system has inversion symmetry, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})&=&\langle u_{-\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle \tag{3}\\
&=& \langle u_{\mathbf{k}}|e^{-i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}i\partial_{\mu}\left(e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}u_{\mathbf{k}}\right)\rangle \tag{4}\\ 
&=& \langle u_{\mathbf{k}}|e^{-i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}ie^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}\partial_{\mu}u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle + \langle u_{\mathbf{k}}|e^{-i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}i^2e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}\tag{4} \\
&=& \langle u_{\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle -\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}} \tag{5}\\
&=&A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}},\tag{6}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where in the second line I used the result for the Bloch state in a system with inversion symmetry, and in the third line the chain rule for differentiation. This result means that for a system that is invariant under inversion, then $A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})$ and $A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$ differ at most by a gauge transformation.

We are now ready to look at the Berry curvature. Under inversion, $\mathcal{I}\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k}$). If the system has inversion symmetry, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k})&=&\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(-\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k}) \tag{7}\\
&=&\partial_{\mu}\left(A_{\nu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}\right)-\partial_{\nu}\left(A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}\right) \tag{8}\\
&=&\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}+\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{\mathbf{k}} \tag{9}\\
&=&\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k}) \tag{10}\\
&=&\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})\tag{11},
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where in the second line I used the result for the Berry connection in a system with inversion symmetry. This proves that for a system with inversion symmetry, $\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k})$.

**Time reversal symmetry.** You can use an analogous procedure (I encourage you to try) to prove that for a time reversal invariant system, $\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=-\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k})$. All you need to know is how the time reversal operator acts on a Bloch state, $\mathcal{T}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle=|u_{\mathbf{-k}}^{\ast}\rangle$, and the rest of the proof proceeds in the same way.

**Physical interpretation.** Berry phase-like quantities look at the evolution of Bloch states at neighbouring $\mathbf{k}$-points in the Brillouin zone. As an example, the Berry connection is looking at the overlap between a state $|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ and a state infinitessimally away from it, $\partial_{\mu}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle$. As such, they are useful for calculation properties that depend on the structure of the Block states across the Brillouin zone. A well-known example is the calculation of topological invariants of materials, which measure the "twists" that the electronic wave function has when crossing the Brillouin zone. I am not familiar with applications in valleytronics, so will leave that for someone more knowledgeable.

**Futher reading.** An excellent book to learn about Berry phase-like quantities and applications (modern theory of polarization, topological materials, etc.) is David Vanderbilt's [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/berry-phases-in-electronic-structure-theory/DDD71CA4FE9AF5F3A2FB300E602F394A).

Comment: +10. Another great one by ProfM!

Comment: @ProfM Thank you for the detailed explanation. What is the physical meaning of the variables $\mu$ and $\nu$? What is the mathematical expression of ${\varphi}_k$? What would the transformation be like for the magnetic moment? Could you give the first example to try to solve for the other transformation, please? I am a beginner in this field and I have tried to see as much as I can in articles, books and workshops but I have not attended Quantum Electrodynamics, I only know the basics of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález $\mu$ and $\nu$ are indices (a bit like the $i$ and $j$ for a matrix $A_{ij}$ but Greek indices are often used when working in spacetime while Latin indices are often used when there's only spatial indices (search "general relativity" in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) to see this). I have added the definition of the derivative symbol to the answer. $R$ is often a nuclear coordinate. As for $\varphi$, it's a [phase](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177599/134583): remember that $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ so states can have a phase (see Bloch sphere).

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I am no expert in the magnetic moment, but in a finite system (e.g. atom) it is given by $\mathbf{m}\propto\int d\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r})$, so I imagine that you need to use how $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ individually transform under inversion and time reversal. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable on that will provide a detailed answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for the answer and for adding that in the previous answer. I still don't quite understand what the notation means. If $\partial_{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial R^{\mu}}$ then $\partial_{\nu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial R^{\nu}}$. $\mathbf{R}$ means the position vector (x, y, z ...), right? So why do we need two different indexes for the position vector, if we only have three spatial coordinates? What does $A_{\mu}$ and $A_{\nu}$ mean? I know that $\mathbf{A}$ represents the Berry connection but I don't understand what the indexes mean. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Unfortunately I don't know anything about the Berry phase. But in Eq 41 of [this PDF by Berry](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry187.pdf) he uses $\partial_i A_j$, not $\partial_\mu A_\nu$, so I am tempted to think that $\mu\in\{x,y,z\}$. The reason for 2 indices might be that they're making a 3x3 matrix $\Omega_{\mu\nu}$ for the pairs: [xx, xy, xz ; yx, yy, yz ; zx, zy, zz]. The abstract of [Berry's original paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1984.0023)calls $R$ a "parameter" of the Hamiltonian, so R could be nuclear positions

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I also see that you have materials questions on Phys.SE that have got 0 upvotes and 0 answers in 5+ months: (1) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530539/134583, (2) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530511/134583, (3) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530341/134583, (4) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439184/134583. Why not copy and paste them here where everyone is nicer and more welcoming? We [need more questions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/5) to convince the Stack Exchange company to keep our site live: it costs them money to store our data

Comment: @CarmenGonzález and NikeDattani, Berry phase-like quantities can be defined with respect to any varying parameter, in the context of a Brillouin zone, the parameter that varies is the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$, so indeed $\mu\in\{x,y,z\}$. I realize this may cause confusion with general relativity notation, but I used it rather than $(i,j)$ because "$i$" already refers to $\sqrt{-1}$. Happy to change notation if you think this is confusing.

Comment: Also, I have updated the answer somewhat to clarify that in 3D there are three independent Berry connections $A_{\mu}$ ($\mu=x,y,z$), and you can think of them as forming a 3-component vector. As @NikeDattani pointed out, the Berry curvature is then a two-index quantity, so a second-rank tensor.

Comment: @ProfM Thanks for making those edits. In my penultimate comment I started writing that the derivative could be with respect to any parameter, and nuclear coordinates could be just one example of that, but I ran out of space in the comment and didn't want to write too much. Now I see that $k$ was a better choice since the rest of your answer uses $k$ rather than R. Good point about $i$ being an imaginary number throughout the rest of your answer. Matrices sometimes use $m,n$ for the rows and columns. But $\mu,\nu$ seems to have been used [here](https://tinyurl.com/BerryCurvature) so it seems ok

Comment: @ProfM Thank you for adding the notations to the response. It was really a good choice of variables, because I didn't realize that there was an imaginary number there. Could you please tell me, how is the transformation of the connection of Berry and the curvature of Berry under time reversal symmetry? I don't know if it is $\mathbf{T}\mathbf{A}_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})=\mathbf{A}_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$ or $\mathbf{T}\mathbf{A}_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})={\mathbf{A}_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})}^{*}$. I'm trying to solve it so I can post it later.

Comment: @ProfM I put in the post my resolution attempt for the time reversal symmetry. Could you check if it's right and correct what's wrong, please? Sorry to be boring, I just wanted to understand the theory well so I could move on to the next part of the theory.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I would recommend that you put everything from "Resolution for the time reversal symmetry" onward (i.e. all the new stuff) into an answer rather than into the question. Then we can comment on the answer and edit it to perfection if it's not already perfect. This will also earn you the ["self-learner" badge](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Comment: @NikeDattani I already put the part of the time reversal symmetry in a separate answer. Do you know if it is well calculated? I did my best but, may be, I missed details.

Answer (score 12):

Resolution for the time reversal symmetry:

I need to demonstrate: $\Omega(-\mathbf{k})=-\Omega(\mathbf{k})$ (Berry's curvature is a odd function under time reversal symmetry)

Berry's curvature:
$$\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})\tag{1}$$

If the system is time-reversally invariant:

$$T|u_k\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle\Rightarrow |u_{-\mathbf{k}}^{*}\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle\tag{2}$$

The time reversal symmetry operator applied to Berry's curvature

$$
\begin{align}
T\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})&=\langle\partial_{\mu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\nu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle-\langle\partial_{\nu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle\tag{5} \\
&=i\int d\mathbf{r}\partial_{\mu}Tu^{\ast}_{\mathbf{k}}\partial_{\nu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}}-i\int d\mathbf{r}\partial_{\nu}Tu^{\ast}_{\mathbf{k}}\partial_{\mu}Tu_{\mathbf{k}} \\
&=i\int d\mathbf{r}\partial_{\mu}u_{-\mathbf{k}}\partial_{\nu}u^{\ast}_{-\mathbf{k}}-i\int d\mathbf{r}\partial_{\nu}u_{-\mathbf{k}}\partial_{\mu}u^{\ast}_{-\mathbf{k}}\\
&=\Omega_{\nu\mu}(-\mathbf{k})\\
&=-\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k}),
\end{align}
$$
where I have used the position representation. Also, the Berry curvature is fully gauge invariant, so time reversal symmetry implies $T\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})$. Putting together the two expressions for $T\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})$ gives:

$$\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=-\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k})\tag{7}$$

Comment: +1. For all the effort that you've shown us that you've put, into answering your own question after the help of ProfM. It might take time for one of us to be able to double-check all your work. By the way, I've edited one of your "equation arrays" so that the equal signs line up properly, can you please do the same for the other equation array, and add \tag{1}, \tag{2}, etc. to label the equations like I did for ProfM's answer?

Comment: +1, great effort! The derivation is almost correct, but not quite. For example, under time reversal the Berry connection transforms as $TA_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})=A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$. Given that you have started so well, I would still recommend that you try to complete the proof yourself, and this online resource explicitly goes through the steps so it can guide you: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Fall_2012/chapter3_part8.pdf

Comment: Also, writing the Berry curvature and connection with subindices indicates the vector or tensor components, so the symbols should not be in bold face. There is often some confusion on this point because although for $n$ parameters the Berry connection is a $n$-component vector and the Berry curvature a $n\times n$ second-rank tensor, if you have 3 parameters (like in this example), then the Berry curvature can be written as a pseudo-vector, so you can work with it as if it were a "vector". This would be an interesting topic for a new question, given our need for questions in the beta...

Comment: @NikeDattani I have already aligned the equations and numbered them. Thanks for the recommendation. I think it became clearer.

Comment: @ProfM I had already seen that document but there are certain details that I didn’t get to understand like the fact that the "i" ($\sqrt{-1}$) is outside the brackets and has a minus sign in front, whereas in the definition you wrote for the Berry connection, the value "i" has a positive/plus sign. I already removed the bold from the Berry connection and the Berry curvature to make it clearer and put $TA_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})=A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$. Would the answer now be 100% correct? What would be missing for the answer to be right? Thank you for the help.

Comment: What he means by "given our need for questions in the beta" is [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/5).

Comment: @ProfM Could you confirm if the answer is correct, please?

Comment: In my notation it should still be an $i$ rather than a $-i$ in the Berry connection (whether it is plus or minus $i$ is a convention, and both definitions are used). Then you would get $A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})=A_{\mu}(\mathbf{k})-\partial_{\mu}\varphi(\mathbf{k})$. For the Berry curvature, it turns out that the application of time reversal symmetry gives $T\Omega_{\mu\nu}(\mathbf{k})=-\Omega_{\mu\nu}(-\mathbf{k})$. Are you happy to have a go or would you like me to provide the solution?

Comment: @ProfM Thank you professor. Could you tell me how to turn $T|u_\mathbf{k}\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_\mathbf{k}\rangle\Rightarrow |u^{*}_\mathbf{-k}\rangle=e^{i\varphi_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_\mathbf{k}\rangle$ into a bra or ket that doesn't have the $^{*}$ in exponent, please? I'm stuck in that step.

Comment: @ProfM Can you change the resolution attempt that I made before or create a new one with the resolution for the time reversal symmetry, please? I'm a little lost in the calculations and I've tried many times but unfortunately I don't get the final result

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, I have now added the solution for the Berry curvature, explicitly working in the position representation to keep track of the complex conjugates more easily.

Comment: @ProfM Thank you for your kindness and effort to edit the answer. In equation (4), it is written that: $A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})=\langle u^{*}_{-\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}u^{*}_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$, but $A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})$ can also be written as follows $A_{\mu}(-\mathbf{k})=\langle u_{-\mathbf{k}}|i\partial_{\mu}u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$. Why are $|u^{*}_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ and $|u_{-\mathbf{k}}\rangle$ the same? In equation (5), $Tu^{*}_\mathbf{k}$ is equal to $u_{-\mathbf{k}}$. Why does it happen? Why are $\Omega_{\nu\mu}$ and $-\Omega_{\mu\nu}$ equal in the same equation?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, my mistake: I only half-edited the expression for $A_{\mu}$ because it is actually not necessary for the Berry connection derivation. Feel free to change it back or to remove it altogether. For your other questions: time reversal changes the momentum and calculates the complex conjugate, so the usual expression is $Tu_{\mathbf{k}}=u_{-\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}$, which immediately implies $Tu^{\ast}_{\mathbf{k}}=u_{-\mathbf{k}}$. The fact that $\Omega_{\mu\nu}=-\Omega_{\nu\mu}$ is a general property of the Berry connection, which you can derive from its definition.

Comment: @ProfM Yes, you are right, Berry's connection is not necessary to prove Berry's curvature in this case. Thank you professor, you are fantastic and tireless! You explained everything so clearly! This post will certainly be very useful because there will certainly be people with the same doubts as me. Can I put that property of Berry's curvature in another question, please? I would also like to understand this property and proof but I cannot find this property on any website or article and so we also help "Matter Modeling" to grow.

Comment: Please do! There's a few people that might answer it.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, I agree with Nike Dattani, please post the question!